# Filter AWS KMS Keys by Tag or by current role which has encrypt/decrypt permissions?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I am writing an API to display a list of kms keys to the user. Based on user selection I need to use that particular KMS key for encryption. Currently, I am displaying all the KMS keys. But I am facing issues while encrypting/decrypting because `lambda_role` does not permissions on that kms key.

How can I filter them on any of the below options

- Get all kms keys where (Tag) product = "product 1" - Planning to Tag the keys with product tag, and fetch by tag
- Get all kms keys where role = "lambda_role" has permission to encrypt/decrypt.

I could not find any AWS API to filter based on any of the options.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [`ListKeys`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_ListKeys.html) API does not fill any of your requirements. The only way I could see to do what you want is to do client-side filtering, i.e. call `ListKeys` and then for each key you care about, call [`ListResourceTags`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_ListResourceTags.html) and [`ListKeyPolicies`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_ListKeyPolicies.html), respectively.